# SeleniumでWebページ上の「もっと見る」ボタン以降のテキスト情報をスクレイピングする

Tags: python, selenium

Seleniumを使い、ページのテキスト情報をスクレイピングで取得しようとしています。
ページの途中に「もっと見る」ボタンがあり、以降の情報もすべて取得したいのですが、
「もっと見る」以前の情報しか取得されず困っています。

```
driver.get("https://r.nikkei.com/search?keyword=%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%83%95%E3%83%AB%E3%82%A8%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B6") #「インフルエンザ」で検索
link_elems = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('search__result-footer') 
for l in link_elems:
  l.click()

text_elems = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('nui-card__head')
text = []
for t in text_elems:
  text.append(t.text)
```

Comment: どうもスクロールバーを下げていって実際に記事のヘッドラインを見る動作を行ったように判断される状態になった時とか、あるいは一定時間間隔で何かの依頼が行われているようです。ブラウザの開発者ツールモード(F12)でNetworkログを取得・表示しつつ動作を確かめてみてください。

Comment: 開発者ツールを見ると、ブラウザで「もっと見る」をクリックすると、上記スクリプトにある'search__result-footer'部分が点滅します。どのように修正すればよいかおわかりになれば教えてください。

Comment: 「もっと見る」ボタンは複数あるのですが、上記スクリプトではボタンがひとつもクリックできていないように思います。xpathで次のように指定しても、クリックできないようです。`link_elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/main/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/button') `

Comment: クエリパラメータ `volume` で取得する件数を設定できますね。例えば `https://r.nikkei.com/search?keyword=...&volume=100` として curl コマンドで GET すると 100 件の情報を取得できます。ただ、「インフルエンザ」で検索すると 3202 件の記事がヒットしますので、全て取得するのはサーバに過大な負荷をかける事になるかと思います。また、もしかしたらサーバ側で最大取得件数を制限している可能性があります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。`volume`でひとまず100件ほど取得しようとしたところ、次のエラーが出てしまいました。`ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: headless chrome=78.0.3904.97)`

Comment: `BeautifulSoup`を使ったところ、100件取得できました。ありがとうございました！

Comment: クエリパラメータ `volume` と BeautifulSoup を使うコードを自己回答として投稿して貰えないでしょうか(個人的に知りたいと思いまして)。

Comment: 以下で取得できました。
`url = https://r.nikkei.com/search?keyword=%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%83%95%E3%83%AB%E3%82%A8%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B6&volume=100
nikkei = requests.get(url)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(nikkei.text, features='lxml')
rvws = soup.find_all(class_="nui-card__title") 
reviews_text = []
for i in range(len(rvws)):
    reviews_text.append(rvws[i].text)`

Comment: 「クエリパラメータ volume で取得する件数を設定できる」というのは、どう調べられたのでしょうか？

Comment: ブラウザ(firefox)のウェブコンソールで HTTP request を確認してみたら、`GET XHR https://r.nikkei.com/.resources/search/partials` という GET が投げられていて、これのクエリパラメータとして `volume` が存在します。また、見落としていたのですが、`offset` というパラメータもあって、おそらくこれは開始位置だと思います。つまり、最初の「もっと見る」ボタンをクリックすると、`https://r.nikkei.com/.resources/search/partials?keyword=...&offset=10&volume=10` が発行されるのだと思います。offset と volume を適宜指定しながら時間を空けてアクセスすれば 3000件の取得は可能かと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます！大変参考になりました。

Comment: たびたびすみません、可能であれば、「ウェブコンソールで HTTP request を確認」を理解するための参考URLなどいただけますでしょうか？別のサイトでも対応できるようにしておきたく。。

Comment: 私の場合、見様見真似で使い方を覚えたので「変な(非効率な)使い方」をしている可能性があります。参考URLも「ウェブコンソール」でググってみる程度でしかありませんので、「ブラウザのウェブコンソールで HTTP request/response を確認する方法」などで質問を立ててみてはどうでしょう？(私もキチンと理解しておきたいと思いますので…)

Comment: 脱線した質問になってしまいすみません、アドバイスありがとうございます！質問を立ててみようと思います。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`driver.find_elements_by_class_name` の返り値は配列なので，`link_elem[0].click()`とやる必要があります．

そもそもの話ですが，そのコードでは，tryブロックのせいでエラーメッセージが握り潰されていてデバッグしづらいので，tryブロックを一旦消すか，エラー内容を表示するようにした方がよさそうです．

Comment: ありがとうございます。スクリプト直しました。やはり「もっと見る」以降の情報が取得できないようです。