# Yahoo!ニュースの検索窓で検索した時の「もっと見る」ボタン以降のテキスト情報をスクレイピングする

Tags: javascript, html, web-scraping

下記の質問とほぼ同じになるのですが、私の力では解決できなかったため同様の質問をさせていただきます。

[Webページ上の「もっと見る」ボタン以降のテキスト情報をスクレイピングする](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/60510)

Yahoo!ニュースの検索窓にキーワードを入力しテキスト情報をスクレイピングで取得しようとしています。
ページの途中に「もっと見る」ボタンがあり、以降の情報もすべて取得したいのですが、
「もっと見る」以前の情報しか取得されず困っています。

上記リンクの回答者さんがFirefoxのデベロッパーツール(「Ctrl」+「Alt」+「Del」)で
コンソールを見れば"Page"とか"Limit"の情報が得られるのでそれでわかるのではないか
とのことでしたがPR TIMESのページでも再現できませんでした。

Firefoxの使い方とか基本的なところからわかっていないだけかも知れませんがなにぶん
初心者なものでどうにもわかりません。ヒントでもよいのでご存知の方ご教示のほど
よろしくお願いいたします。

そもそもこのやり方でわかるものかどうかもわかっていません。

[image: Firefoxのデベロッパーツールで開いた結果は下記画像の通りです。]

Comment: [robots.txt](https://news.yahoo.co.jp/robots.txt) の記述を見る限り、(検索結果の) スクレイピングは禁止しているものと見られます。

Comment: スクレイピング禁止はサイト側が勝手に謳っているだけで、法的に禁止されているわけではありません。そもそもスクレイピングができなかったら検索エンジンなどのサービスは成り立ちませんから。過度にサイトにアクセスしたりしてサーバーを麻痺させたりすれば偽計業務妨害罪等に問われるでしょうが。というか、この話は質問の本筋と関係ないと思います。

Comment: API の URL は `https://news.yahoo.co.jp/api/searchFeed` で、query word は、`query`(検索文字列) と `results`(取得件数)、`start`(記事のインデックス)と API token です。API token はトップページに JavaScript の変数(ハッシュ)として埋め込まれているので、それを抽出する必要があります。

Comment: 「検索窓」で検索した結果ではなくYahooニュースの各カテゴリに提示されている記事ならこちらの記事で出来るかもしれませんね。[【Python】YahooニュースのAPIがないのでスクレイピングする](https://self-development.info/%E3%80%90python%E3%80%91yahoo%E3%83%8B%E3%83%A5%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B9%E3%81%AEapi%E3%81%8C%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E3%81%AE%E3%81%A7%E3%82%B9%E3%82%AF%E3%83%AC%E3%82%A4%E3%83%94%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0%E3%81%99/)

Comment: 「Yahoo!ニュースの検索窓にキーワードを入力しテキスト情報をスクレイピングで取得」とのことですが、どのような手法でスクレイピングされる予定でしょうか？（Firefoxについて言及されているのでFirefoxを自動操作するのでしょうか？）

Comment: metropolisさん情報ありがとうございます。Yahoo!ニュースのWeb APIについてはkunifさんに教えていただいたページを見ると2014年で公開が終わっているようですが(私もかすかな記憶が・・・https://techblog.yahoo.co.jp/web/news/yahoo_japan_web_api_close/)、新たに取得できるようになったのでしょうか？それはどちらのページを参照すれば見られますか？なにからなにまで質問で申し訳ありません。

Comment: @kobo_jp ブラウザのデベロッパーツールで見ると、`https://news.yahoo.co.jp/api/searchFeed` に HTTP POST で検索ワードなどを投げている様子が確認できます。(レスポンスは JSON 形式)  URL に Feed と入っているので RSS リーダ向けの API なのではないかな、と推測しています。

Comment: kunifさん情報ありがとうございます。教えていただいたリンク先の記事を読みました。Yahoo!ニュースのWeb APIは公開が終わっていたんですね。各カテゴリの記事はRSSで取得できるようですが、確かRSSで取得できる記事は一部に限られていたと思います。あとできればカテゴリ別ではなく全体を取得したいですし。ともあれ情報ありがとうございました。

Comment: merinoさんこんばんは。Firefoxを自動操作するのではなく、Googleスプレッドシートと連携したGAS(Google Apps Script)で取得する実験を行っています。GASはVisual Basicを応用したExcel VBAのように、Javascriptを応用したものなのでJavaScriptのコードである程度いけます。こんな感じです。`function getYahooNews(url) { // HTMLの生コードを取得
  let source = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText('UTF-8');
  return source;
}`

Comment: @metropolis ブラウザのデベロッパーツールで確認できるんですね。よく確認するのですが、どこを見たら見られるのか未だにわからなくて・・・。RSSだと情報は一部だけということになりますね。丁寧に解説いただきありがとうございました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> API の URL は `https://news.yahoo.co.jp/api/searchFeed` で、query word は、query(検索文字列) と results(取得件数)、start(記事のインデックス)と API token です。API token はトップページに JavaScript の変数(ハッシュ)として埋め込まれているので、それを抽出する必要があります。

「トヨタ」で検索すると 10,000 件以上もあるので、以下のコードでは最初の 300 件を取得しています。

```py
import requests
import re
import sys
import time
from pprint import pprint

yahoo_news_url = 'https://news.yahoo.co.jp/'
search_url = 'https://news.yahoo.co.jp/api/searchFeed'

# get API token
r = requests.get(yahoo_news_url)
r.raise_for_status()
token = re.search(r'"apiAccessToken":"(.+?)"', r.text)
if token is None: sys.exit(1)
token = token[1]

# get news feed
query = 'トヨタ'
start, num_feeds, num_repeats = 1, 50, 6  # 50 articles * 6 repeats = 300 articles
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
articles = []
for idx in range(start, num_feeds*num_repeats, num_feeds):
    params = {'query': query, 'start': idx, 'results': num_feeds, 'token': token}
    r = requests.get(search_url, params=params, headers=headers)
    r.raise_for_status()

    js = r.json()
    for c in js['contents']:
        if 'contentId' in c:
            headline = re.sub(r'[\x02\x03]', '', c['highlightSearchText']['headline'])
            body_text = '…' + re.sub(r'[\x02\x03]', '', c['highlightSearchText']['body']) + '…'
            articles.append({
                'headline': headline, 'body': body_text,
                'publishTime': c['publishTime'], 'permalink': c['permalink']})

    time.sleep(10)

total_results = js['totalResults']

# show results
print(f'{query = }')
print(f'{total_results = }')
pprint(articles, sort_dicts=False, width=150)
```

**出力結果**

```py
query = 'トヨタ'
total_results = 10471
[{'headline': '【バレー】埼玉上尾・山岸あかねがVリーグ出場通算230試合出場達成。女子の大卒選手では史上2人目',
  'body': '…で、史上2人目の快挙となった。同チームでは3月5日の第2試合（埼玉上尾対トヨタ車体戦）後に受賞セレモニーを行う予定。 \u3000山岸選手のプロフィールは以下の通り。…',
  'publishTime': {'date': '3/5(日)', 'time': '1:01'},
  'permalink': 'https://news.yahoo.co.jp/articles/bbee4c9c54db4861de8189f914cdb864bc272f2a'},
 {'headline': '【ハイライト動画あり】横浜キヤノンイーグルスvs.静岡ブルーレヴズ、金曜夜の決戦は激戦の末のドロー。ジャパンラグビー リーグワン第10節',
  'body': '…の静岡ブルーレヴズが挑んだ。 トップ4入りを目指すイーグルスは、前節もトヨタヴェルブリッツを39-7で下し、3連勝。沢木啓介監督は前節からFW（フォ…',
  'publishTime': {'date': '3/4(土)', 'time': '21:42'},
  'permalink': 'https://news.yahoo.co.jp/articles/93246093f24965722a153a86cbbd81c60966317a'},

                                        :
```

Comment: 凄い！次のリンクで無事2ページ目が取得できました！Tokenがキモなんですね。よくこんなことをご存知と感心しました。本当に本当にありがとうございました。
[https://news.yahoo.co.jp/api/searchFeed?query=%E3%83%88%E3%83%A8%E3%82%BF&start=51&results=50&token=（https://news.yahoo.co.jpのトップページから取得したapiAccessToken）](https://news.yahoo.co.jp/api/searchFeed?query=%E3%83%88%E3%83%A8%E3%82%BF&start=51&results=50&token=（https://news.yahoo.co.jpのトップページから取得したapiAccessToken）)